# How do I remove items from a 2-d array based on randomised conditions?

Tags: c#, .net, xna

I have a small game (5 classes) being developed in XNA. There are balls bouncing around the window, moving at right-angles when colliding with the sides of the window. The user creates a marquee by dragging the mouse anywhere in the window. When the marquee is created and confirmed, every time a ball hits the marquee it is to be removed. I have my balls in a 2-d array, and I wondered how to remove the balls from this type of array. Currently I am doing the following:

```
Rectangle ball = new Rectangle((moveBallX - 4), (moveBallY - 4), moveBallX, moveBallY);
Rectangle marquee = new Rectangle(tempInitialX, tempInitialY, tempWidth, tempHeight);
if (ball.Intersects(marquee))
{
    balls[rowIndex, columnIndex].SetRed(0);
    balls[rowIndex, columnIndex].SetGreen(0);
    balls[rowIndex, columnIndex].SetBlue(0);
}
```

This makes the balls that enter the marquee black, so as they become invisible. I want to do other things with the code such as display the number of balls remaining on the board, so being able to remove the items from the array would be useful.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Why are the balls in a 2D array (and not a 1D one)? Just curious

Comment: Good question. I found it easier to deploy them in a 2D array to begin with, because they flash and rotate colours while stationary for the first five seconds of the game. They were then arranged in a grid which was flexible to the game window, if it changed. For these reasons I chose to use a 2D array.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the spot in the array where the ball is to `null`. This is fast and simple (no array resizing required), but you'll have to change all your loops to check for nulls first.

So the code would look something like this:

```
if (ball.Intersects(marquee))
{
    var deadBall = balls[rowIndex, columnIndex];
    balls[rowIndex, columnIndex] = null;

    deadBall.SetRed(0);
    deadBall.SetGreen(0);
    deadBall.SetBlue(0);
}
```

Keep in mind that you can keep track of the ball count in a separate variable; this is easier (and faster) than counting the number of non-null balls in your array.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to remove items, use a List, unless there's some need to have a statically sized 2d array of the balls. You mentioned they were bouncing around the screen though, so it doesn't seem necessary to keep them in row/col cels.

```
List<Ball> balls = new List<Ball>();

// Initialize the balls into a grid structure:
for( int i=0; i < numberOfRows; i++ )
    for( int j=0; j < numberOfColumns; j++ )
        balls.Add( new Ball( i * gridWidth, j * gridHeight, Color.Blue );

// ... some other code probably goes here ...

var trash = balls.Where( ball => ball.Intersects( marquee ) );
foreach( Rectangle ball in trash )
    balls.Remove( ball );
```

To cut down on the amount of code you'd have to write, I'd also modify your Ball class to include a few more functions, like this:

```
public class Ball
{
    int X;
    int Y;
    Color color;

    public Ball( int x, int y, Color c )
    {
        X = x; Y = y; color = c;
    }

    // Whatever else you have in your ball class goes here

    public bool Intersects( Rectangle rect )
    {
        return new Rectangle( this.X - 4, this.Y - 4, this.X, this.Y ).Intersects( rect );
    }


    public void MakeInvisible()
    {
        color = new Color( 0, 0, 0, 0 );
    }
}
```